# Problemas para hacer funcionar SFML en codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Al intentar correr el codigo de prueba que viene por defecto en SFML, sale el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo instalado el compilador GCC 13.1.0 MinGW (SEH) - 64-bit de SFML y codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup. No sale ningun mensaje de error en otro momento, segui tal cual lo hacen otras personas el procedimiento de agregar los archivos en settings>compiler. Alguna solucion?

Comment: Comprueba que no estés enlazando las librerías de 32bits en un proyecto de 64bits o viceversa.

Comment: Necesitamos más información. Cómo configuraste el proyecto y sería útil saber de cuál link descargaste librería. Ten en cuenta que si la librería es de C++, fue compilada con otro compilador y no usa `extern "C" ...` fallará porque cada compilador tiene su propio name mangling.